# PHP upload text to file

Tags: php, html

I am after some help with some code for a HTML feature.

I am wanting to get information from two textboxes on a web site (txtName,txtBody), and then save the contents of these textboxes to a file on an ftp server using PHP.

Can someone point me in the correct direction to do this?

thanks

Comment: file_put_contents($file,$_POST['txtName']); very raw example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File put contents can be used to accomplish this as dagon says, below is a simple example.

```
<?php
    $file = 'people.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    //Assign txtName to variable.
    $name = $_POST['txtName'];
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= $name;
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dealing with `ftp` then you have to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php

```
$file = $_POST['txtName'];
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['txtBody']);
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
```